# Polybase and 'Azure to Azure' load speeds chart

Tags: database, azure, polybase

I apologize for this not being a programming question, but I am looking for a matrix chart provided by Microsoft demonstrating the loading speeds going to and from each Azure data related resource (I just found it a few months ago but lost the link, so it's not that old...). For example, the chart noted loading data to and from Synapse Analytics noting data movement speeds from storage, up to 1.5 GB/s to Azure SQL db, being much less, etc.

Does anyone recall the location of this chart?

Comment: This one?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808469/best-method-to-transfer-and-transfrom-large-amount-of-data-from-a-sql-server-to/53817929

Comment: @wBob that's it! I see that it's no longer contained in the main MSFT doc though, maybe they just did away with it

Comment: Hi @Sauron, the chart is still exist, I shared the Azure document for you in the answer.

Comment: Hello @Sauron, do you have any other concerns?  If the answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ref my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53817929/10549281

[image]

The picture is in this Azure document: [Copy Activity performance and tuning guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-copy-activity-performance#performance-reference)